# What are the network Localhost 8545 settings in Metamask?

Tags: metamask, wallets, networkid

I was trying to add another network to my metamask and I accidentally deleted the Localhost 8545 network. I was wondering if this could do any harm. Would anyone know what the settings of the Custom RPC would be to get it back?

Answer (score 2):

No harm, you can always add it back. This is just the standard local development url.

Comment: The chain id value depends on the node that is running at your computer. For Ethereum mainnet it is 1. For other networks, like testnets, see here https://chainlist.org/

Answer (score 0):

No harm. You can start the RPC by executing admin.startRPC("127.0.0.1",8545) again if you need it.

Comment: This doesn't work for adding localhost network to metamask.